# Search page source of all the pages of a domain for keywords using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, url, selenium, webdriver

I am going to make a script in java using selenium webdriver. So the flow is like this, I need to search the page source of all the pages of a domain having keywords as vfstate.js and .force.com. The end result I need is to output all those pages where the page source has these keywords.

I can implement that, just need to know what would be the logic here.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? is the problem to get all pages or like @Stanjer statet the page source?

Answer (score 0):

So, what is the exact problem?

1) getting the source of the page with
`String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();`

2) getting known if any of strings exist in your array of strings 'myStrings' in a loop with something like:
`pageSource.contains(myStrings[i].toLowerCase())`